# how to get the oldest file by modified date in directory with csv extension and copy it with another name

Tags: linux, unix

I have list of files in directory

```
example

aa_11.csv
aa_22.csv
```

what I want to do is find oldest file by modified date and copy it with name "final.csv"

Thank in Advance

Comment: What attempts did you make?

Comment: ls -1 -t /path/to/directory/*.csv | head -1                                                            but i think there should be better way of doing it . UNIX is not my domain

Comment: Appreciate you posting it and what is wrong with the way you did?

Comment: I dont know i feel there is better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Single line run from the directory in question:

```
cp `ls -t | head -1` final.csv
```

(note the back ticks, NOT apostrophes)